# Why my site show on microsoft edge correctly and dont show correct on firefox?

Tags: html

I'm beginner in html and want to design simple site,i write any html code on my web and html head tag code is:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Shop Homepage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

but that code just show me correct in microsoft edge,and dont show correct on firefox or any browser,how can i solve that?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be misunderstanding the purpose of this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

That line does NOT mean "will work in Microsoft Edge"

It instructs current and older versions of the Internet Explorer browser (and NOT edge) to use the most current document processing rules, rather than try to guess at the web developer's expectations as to how the web page document should be processed in Internet Explorer.

When the web developer includes the meta header, it tells IE to always assume that the web developer has tested the website against the latest version of IE, specifically regarding the "Compatibility Mode" of IE, and does not want IE trying to turn on Compatibility View.

Chrome, Firefox, and other browsers will ignore that line.